# Getting unexpected results from regex.test() and my debugged code (filled with logs) works but I don't know why

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find all instances of a query within a set of data pulled from my workbook. The query could be found in one of two columns and may exist in one or multiple rows.

The solution I came up with works, I've tested it with multiple cases using [Quokka.js](https://quokkajs.com/) before moving my code to the [Apps Script IDE](https://www.google.com/script/start/).

Once I ran my code with actual operating data I noticed that regex.test() is returning true for an arbitrary amount of rows. I starting adding some logs to debug and for some reason adding an `if statement` with a log cause the rest of the code to work, which makes no sense.

This is an example of how the data looks in the sheet:

| Query 1 | Query 2 | Title | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 000A | Title 1 | 2 |
| 0001 | 000B | Title 2 | 4 |
| 0002 | 000C | Title 3 | 1 |
| 0003 | 000A | Title 4 | 2 |
| 0001 | 000D | Title 5 | 1 |

All of this data is being stored into a matrix called `orders` that will look like this:

```js
[
 [0001, '000A', 'Title 1', 2],
 [0001, '000B', 'Title 2', 4],
 ...
]
```

This is the code that *does not* work properly:

```js
// @param {Matrix} orders → row of matrix = [supplierID, tracking, ...others]
// @param {String||Integer} query → supplier Id, tracking, etc.
// @return {Array} instances → array of every row index that contains the query
function searchOrdersMatrix(orders, query) {
    query = query.toString();
    const regex = new RegExp(query, 'gi');
    const instances = [];

    for (let n = 0; n < orders.length; ++n) {
        const row = orders[n].join('');
        const rowMatches = regex.test(row);
        if (rowMatches) instances.push(n + 2);
    }

    return instances;
}
```

This is the does that *does* work properly:

```js
// @param {Matrix} orders → row of matrix = [supplierID, tracking, ...others]
// @param {String||Integer} query → supplier Id, tracking, etc.
// @return {Array} instances → array of every row index that contains the query
function searchOrdersMatrix(orders, query) {
  query = query.toString();
    const regex = new RegExp(query, 'gi');
    const instances = [];

    for (let n = 0; n < orders.length; n++) {
        const row = orders[n].join('');
        const rowMatches = regex.test(row);
        if (rowMatches) Logger.log(`Row ${n+2} Regex result: ${regex.test(row)}`);
        if (rowMatches) {
           instances.push(n + 2);
           Logger.log(`Pushed row ${n + 2}`)
        }
    }

    return instances;
}
```

In both cases, `regex` is going to follow this structure (example query): `/0001/gi`, and `row` is going to look like this (again, example data): `'0001000ATitle 12`.

So there are a few things I don't understand about this:

1. The first block of code works, but only for some of the rows despite them all containing the query.
2. The second block of code results in all of the rows being stored, but if I remove the first `if statement` it returns the same result as the first block of code.
3. Although the second block of code works, the log in the first `if statement` looks like this:

> Row 2 Regex: false,
> Pushed row 2
>
> Row 3 Regex: false,
> Pushed row 3
>
> Row 5 Regex: false,
> Pushed row 5
>
> Row 6 Regex: false,
> Pushed row 6
>
> Row 7 Regex: false,
> Pushed row 7

Why is `const rowMatches = regex.test(row);` true but `${regex.test(row)}` false?

Given my actual data set, my expected output for `instances` is `[2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 13.0, 14.0, 16.0, 17.0]`.

This is the logged result from the first block of code:[image: first log]

and this is the logged result from the second block of code:[image: second log]

I had a hard time giving this question a title given that it's not necessarily a problem with `regex.test()` & the code does *technically* work, so please let me know if there is a more accurate way to describe this question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-does-a-regexp-with-global-flag-give-wrong-results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are using a regular expression with the global flag, as those are stateful. When calling [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test), it will update the regular expression object's `lastIndex` property and the next time, it will only start matching from this `lastIndex`. This is obviously undesirable when using the same regular expression instance on multiple strings. To remedy this, simply remove the global (`g`) flag when constructing the `RegExp` (which is not needed when just checking for a partial match):

```js
const regex = new RegExp(query, 'i');
```

Comment: Oh I understand, so does the second block of code return all of the matches because the first if statement is resetting the lastIndex to 0?